# Where will custom VBO objects stored in blue prism

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I have uninstalled the SQL server used in Blue Prism and now i am not able to find the VBO objects created in Blue Prism.Will the VBO and process get stored locally?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Blue Prism work processes and VBO objects were stored in SQL server folder as .mdf file and pasted those files in newly installed SQL server folder.

Answer (score 0):

All Processes and Objects in Blue Prism are stored in your SQL Server/SQL Express database.

If you've deleted your database, they're likely gone forever.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the following cheat sheet:
https://www.cheatography.com/ethanium/cheat-sheets/blue-prism-vbo/

From what I have experienced in the past, it is stored locally on the BP database. You may however, be using a different version to me. I am on 5.

Comment: I am not able to understand the cheat sheet. And am using Blue Prism 5

Comment: have you imported VBO itself yet?
On v5 open production database or 'prod', Click File, Import, From the resulting dialog, browse to the VBO folder within the directory in which Blue Prism was installed and open the folder Blue Prism Automate and then select VBO.

Continue then to import